# can anyone tell me why i'm getting this error ?, i already install datareader package

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
```

i already install datareader package but still i get this Error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'StringIO' from 'pandas.compat' (D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py)
```

Comment: I guess is necessary also upgrade pandas

Comment: i upgrade pandas,Now i got this Error                                                
                                                                                                           
                                                                                                           
       ImportError: cannot import name 'StringIO' from 'pandas.compat' (D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py)

Answer (score 0):

The soulution:

> pip3 install --upgrade pandas==0.24.2

then:

```
pip install pandas-datareader
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is pandas 0.25.0 has removed pandas.compat. So go back to 0.24.2

```
pip install "pandas<0.25.0"
```

or

```
pipenv install "pandas<0.25.0"
```